# Isekai manga - protagonist has his RPG account stolen, commits suicide, wakes up inside backup account

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I am looking for an isekai manga I read before. The male protagonist, who was a first-ranker in a RPG-like game, had his account named Seven stolen and commits suicide (or just falls asleep thinking about it, I don't remember), and when he wakes up, he is in his second account, named "Second" in the world of the game he played.

Comment: This is quite brief can you remember anything else about this? Also are you saying it’s an isekai because he does? If so how sure are you about that because you think he might fall asleep? If it’s the latter then this doesn’t seem science fictional or fantastical per your description.

Comment: im sure he got isekai d but i dont remember if he committed suicide or just fell asleep thinking about it and got isekaid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Moto Sekai Ichi'i Subchara Ikusei Nikki: Hai Player, Isekai wo Kouryakuchuu!* (2018), which translates to *The Former Top 1's Sub-Character Training Diary ~A Dedicated Player is Currently Conquering Another World!~*.

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/moto-sekai-ichii-subchara-ikusei-nikki-hai-player-isekai-wo-kouryakuchuu):

> The protagonist who was rarely ever at school during his middle school and high school days, is unemployed even as an adult. From morning till night, it was video games. **For him who was ranked first worldwide, it was his life. One day, his character is suddenly hacked.** The data was unrecoverable and there was nothing that could be done. Feeling great despair at having lost his rank that he had bet everything to achieve in a world that controlled his life, **the protagonist attempts suicide.** When he awakens, he finds himself inside the video game, no, it was a real world that resembled it. There, **he notices that he has reincarnated into the the body of a sub character that he had created** and bought premium benefits for long ago but had left neglected.

---

Found with the Google query `isekai manga account stolen "named second"` which returned, in page 2 of the results, the following description:

> - "Seven" is the top 1 player of the virtual game Mobius Online until his account suddenly gets hacked
> - Unable to fathom his lost title, he kills himself in real life but reawakens inside the game
> - Using his spare avatar named "Second", he is dead set to re-claim his glory by any means possible

Comment: No link is given for the second quote as it would link to a copyright-infringing website. [Related Meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13046/98028).

Comment: thank you bud. i was searching desperately in google or manga sites for hours :D <3